# Pandas pivot_table: "merge" column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Assume I have the following table:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

d = [[datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1, minute=5), "A", "new", 3],
     [datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1, minute=5), "B", "new", 6],
     [datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1, minute=5), "C", "new", 7],
     [datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1, minute=15), "A", "old", 6],
     [datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1, minute=15), "B", "old", 2],
     [datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1, minute=15), "C", "old", 14],
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=["Time", "Article", "Status", "Qty"])
```

I want to restructure this data such, that I have one line per "Time"-value and then for each article the columns "Qty" and "Status".

This I can nearly achieve using the pivot_table as follows:

```
pd.pivot_table(data=df, index=["Time"], columns=["Article"], values=["Status", "Qty"], aggfunc="last")
```

Which produces the following output for me:

|  | Qty |  |  | Status |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Article | A | B | C | A | B | C |
| Time |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021-01-01 00:05:00 | 3 | 6 | 7 | new | new | new |
| 2021-01-01 00:15:00 | 6 | 2 | 14 | old | old | old |

However, I would like this to be grouped by the Article, rather than the value columns. So like it would be produced by the following code:

```
arrays = [
    ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "qux", "qux"],
    ["Qty", "Status", "Qty", "Status", "Qty", "Status"],
]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["Article", "Value"])
data_pivot=[
    [3, "new", 6, "new", 6, "new"],
    [6, "old", 2, "old", 14, "old"]
]
pd.DataFrame(data=data_pivot, columns=index, index=[datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1, minute=5), datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=1, minute=15)])
```

| Article | A |  | B |  | C |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Value | Qty | Status | Qty | Status | Qty | Status |
| 2021-01-01 00:05:00 | 3 | new | 6 | new | 6 | new |
| 2021-01-01 00:15:00 | 6 | old | 2 | old | 14 | old |

Simply switching the values- and columns-keyword in the pivot_table-call somehow didn't give me the expected output either.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble naming this issue so it's a bit hard for me to look for existing solutions (hence, the maybe strange title of this question), so I'm sorry if this was already asked many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.swaplevel(1,0,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```